# Resources with dynamic segments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails 4 application, I have the following code:

```
 get "products/:token" => "products#show"
 delete "products/:token" => "products#destroy"
 ... (for each HTTP method)
```

I've read the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, but can't figure out if there is just a way to do:

```
resources :products
```

and have it default to the :token segment instead of :id.

I tried this:

```
def to_param
  token
end
```

but this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define the parameter key by using the [`param`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L982) option as follows:

```
resources :products, param: :token
```

This will give you `param[:token]` instead of `param[:id]`.

Comment: Thanks so much! That should be added to the Rails Guides

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to override your `to_param` method, then you will need to use `:id` since that's what `to_param` uses. So change the `:token` to `:id`.